# Django make_password too slow for creating large list of users programatically

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to create hundreds (possibly thousands) of users programatically in Django. I am using something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
for username, email, pwd in big_user_list:
    m = User(username=username, email=email, password=make_password(pwd))
    m.save()
```

This is taking too long to execute. I've confirmed that make_password is the culprit by running the above script without passwords.

Is there anyway around this slowness issue, I really need this script to execute quickly.

Comment: You can pass a salt and your own hashing algorithm to `make_password` as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the `django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher` for an initial password. As per [Django docs on how Django stores passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/passwords/),

> **By default, Django uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash**, a
>   password stretching mechanism recommended by NIST. This should be
>   sufficient for most users: it’s quite secure, **requiring massive
>   amounts of computing time to break.**
>
> [...]
>
> Django chooses the an algorithm by consulting the PASSWORD_HASHERS
>   setting. This is a list of hashing algorithm classes that this Django
>   installation supports. **The first entry in this list** (that is,
>   settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS[0]) **will be used** [by default] **to store passwords, and all
>   the other entries are valid hashers that can be used to check existing
>   passwords.** [...]
>
> The default for PASSWORD_HASHERS is:
>
> ```
> PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher'
> )
> ```

Thus you'd want to keep the default as it is now, but use a weaker hasher in the beginning; make sure that the `MD5PasswordHasher` is present in the list. Then use

```
make_password(pwd, None, 'md5')
```

to generate a plain salted MD5 password initially; this will not be too weak provided that the initial password is random enough. As the users change their passwords, their passwords will be encrypted with a stronger algorithm.

Comment: Good idea!  But **only** if the initial password you give them is indeed a really good one - e.g. a completely random 12-character ASCII string.