# HMAC Authentication using Django - Shared Secret

Tags: python, django, authentication, hmac

For those who read this later: This was part of a hobby project I was doing and back then I wasn't aware of such a thing called Let's Encrypt! Also, I didn't want to purchase an SSL cert; so I was trying to have SOME security without `https`. Signing does not replace encryption. If you wanna do what I wanted to do, don't. Get a cert from Let's Encrypt. It's Easier and more secure!

---

I am implementing a web service using Django for a mobile app. I decided to use Hash-MAC to authenticate requests (no Oath, no https) but the challenge is what should I use as the shared secret key?

First I considered using The user's password but it required to store passwords in plain text in server-side database. The other solution that came to my mind was salting and hashing password in the mobile app just the way that Django auth app does in order to compute hashed password on client-side.

1. What does Django use as salt? Are they "secret"? Is there any problem with sending them as plain-text to users? We don't have to keep salts as "secret"s in general, but Django may use something that should be kept secret as salts, I don't know, it is about how Django implemented this.
2. Users have to know their salts to compute a hashed password, so the server should provide them with it. An adversary can ask for all users salts and eventually (s)he can have all the salts (Even if there is a limit to the number of times someone can ask for this in a certain time period). Even though salts are not secret but I guess knowing "all" of them can be dangerous. (or maybe I am overly concerned about security!)

Requests format:

```
HTTP request header:
x-mac-digest: 1d186b9c0fd5cd393f23623f0d167f7b17ac7d1cd74d8442647991d61e756c19

HTTP request body:
{
  "username": "mjafar",
  ... rest of request in json
}
```

Authenticating request (simplified):

```
hash_digest = request.META['HTTP_X_MAC_DIGEST']
request_body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
request_json = json.loads(request_body)

user = UserModel.objects.get(username=request_json['username'])
sharedKey = getSharedKey(user)  # What should it return?

hash = hmac.new(sharedKey, request_body, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
if hash != hash_digest:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest('MAC authentication failed')
```

Comment: Also, what's the problem here, What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ahmed I'm trying to authenticate requests to web server without sending passwords or access tokens in plain text.

Comment: What is sent to server: (message, username, hash(message||password))

Comment: How are you going to transfer the password in the first place?

Comment: @Ahmed That's the point, since user and server both know the password there won't be any transfers. I wanna implement make_password in client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMAC is used to authenticate a block of messages. It's used to verify block of cipher/Text was not changed during the transmission. You will need to use asymmetric encryption (RSA, DH,..etc) to transfer your shared key.

Using a plain text without using digital signature is useless. You will be vulnerable to MITM attack. Unless you manage to put the shared secret on the mobile app without internet (GSM SIM cards have shared key inside the sim itself and it's used to encrypt GSM calls).

Django uses random function to generate its secret_key. Random function on Linux will call /dev/urandom, on windows will call what's equivalent to that.

In your case, create a rest api to create a username and password, then return a hash value to be used to access your views.

If you want to compute a custom hash value, you can call make_password function, and save it directly in the password attribute in User

Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/

Example: [Django make_password too slow for creating large list of users programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273110/django-make-password-too-slow-for-creating-large-list-of-users-programatically)

Comment: This answers my first question (upvoted), if you could answer the second one (even in comments) that would be so helpful

Comment: You can transfer salt via DH, then have a shared salt between client and server. However, you need to understand that your messages will be seen in the network, and if you're not using digital signature, it will be possible to do MITM attack first time transferring the salt.

Comment: Transfer salt first time in the phone and server. If the phone user the login or install the app on a new phone, ask user to submit password, then hashed with the salt, and if it correct, send the salt back again to the user via DH

Comment: NOT DH, but RSA if you want to reuse the old salt again.

Answer (score 0):

django-hmac-authentication authenticates users with separate protected hmac keys.[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/django-hmac-authentication/)