# Django 1.9 Bulk Create New Users Not hashing Passwords Correctly

Tags: python, django

I want to read in some data from a file to quickly create many test accounts. I'd prefer to use the bulk_create method since this is typically much faster for adding many records to a model. However, when using the bulk_create method with Django's User model the passwords aren't being hashed correctly meaning I'm then unable to log in and out as a user.

```
    User.objects.bulk_create([
        User(
            username=name,
            email='sample@email.co.uk',
            password='Sample&Password!',
            is_active=True,
        ) for name in f.read().splitlines()
    ])
```

Django admin shows the following error in each User's password field

> Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.

The second method however continues to work (albeit much slower).

```
    for name in f.read().splitlines():
        User.objects.create_user(
            name,
            'sample@email.co.uk',
            password="Sample&Password!"
        ).save()
```

My question is, is there a way to properly bulk create users in one go in Django. Does Django behave like this for a reason or is this a bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`make_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password). This ensures that hashed passwords are stored in your database. If `make_password` is too slow, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18273177/6463237)

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

User.objects.bulk_create([
    User(
        username=name,
        email='sample@email.co.uk',
        password=make_password('Sample&Password!'),
        is_active=True,
    ) for name in f.read().splitlines()
])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because password are encrypted in the database and you're saving the original. You simply need to use `make_password` to encrypt it.

Please try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

User.objects.bulk_create([
    User(
        username=name,
        email='sample@email.co.uk',
        password=make_password('Sample&Password!'),
        is_active=True,
    ) for name in f.read().splitlines()
])
```