# Django: speed up hundreds of users upload

Tags: python, django, bulkinsert

### Problem

I am currently developing an app and deploying it on Heroku. One important function is that the admin should be able to **upload hundreds of users** at a time by uploading a `.csv` file. The problem is that, using Heroku's free plan due to budget constraints, it is taking too long and the **request time ran out**. I need a better solution to deal with this problem.

### My Attempt

My current practice now is that I use `create_user()` to register new user to the database (code attached below).

```
def register_user(upload_file, file_type):
    if file_type == 'csv':
        reader = csv.reader(StringIO(upload_file), delimiter=',')
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            else:
                username = row[0]
                password = row[1]
                if username.isdigit():
                    is_staff = False
                else:
                    is_staff = True
                try:
                    User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, is_staff=is_staff)
                except:
                    continue
```

The reason I don't use `bulk_create()` is that I have to keep track of how many users are skipped/not added to the database. (Though this may not be the best practice.)

### Some Discovery

- My attempt works completely fine in `localhost`. With ~300 users, it takes around 10 seconds.
- From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273110/django-make-password-too-slow-for-creating-large-list-of-users-programatically), I already understood that the `create_user()` is taking too long due to the process of making passwords. So I decided to use Argon2 hasher instead of the default one. The performance already boosted significantly, but still not enough.
- `bulk_create()` does speed the process up, but almost insignificant in `localhost`.

Is there any way to prevent request timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `create_user` is internally doing a call to [QuerySet.create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create). This function is internally using the object constructor to create an instance and then it is using the object's `save` method to persist it.

I.e. these snippets are most likely equivalent

```
User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, is_staff=is_staff)
```

```
u = User(username=username, password=password, is_staff=is_staff)
u.save()
```

You could measure the time it takes around each one of those calls. My bet is that the saving is taking up the biggest part, as it has to establish (or get a cached one) connection to the database, create an SQL query, execute it and return the result.

Django's ORM offers a convenient function for batching up all those queries into one: [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). Switching to this function will have a significant effect if your DB is running on a different host.

With this your code would look something like the following. I have also taken the liberty to clean up your code.

```
def register_users(upload_file, file_type):
    if file_type != 'csv':
        # TODO raise error here
        return
    reader = csv.DictReader(upload_file)
    users = []
    for row in reader:
        is_staff = not row['username'].isdigit()
        users.append(User(username=row['username'], password=row['password'], is_staff=is_staff))
    try:
        User.objects.bulk_create(users)
    except:
        # TODO: Catch specific expected exceptions and log them
       continue
```

If this optimisation does not get the query under one second, I would debug the internals of `bulk_create` to see whether there is some lazily evaluated functions (like the hashes you mentioned).

Note that I did not test any of the above.

---

Aside from this small improvement, this kind of processes is usually done best asynchronously in background. You can return to the requester straight away and optionally provide the status of the upload as a separate API end point. This will lower the requirement on request timings and will free up one request thread.

It might be worth using a queue and/or a separate service for this bulk upload, depending on your application's profile.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The performance did get significantly better. Last time, I tried to use `bulk_create()`, it was performed only in local. The **connection to database** should also be taken in account.

Comment: According to your edit, could you please give a suggestion about which framework/library I have to look it up? @hubert

Comment: You do not need any frameworks or libraries for this, @gunsodo. Once a CSV file is uploaded, you can return to the HTTP request immediately. Then, outside of the request scope, you can have a separate service that is triggered using a file watcher or cron. This other service would take the CSV file and work on the DB. If your service is running on a single machine and the CSVs are uploaded to the same, you can use the existence of the file as the concurrency lock. This would run outside the request/response cycle, so you would usually want to add visibility through logging or another endpoint.